# 2 different logins accessing different themes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, themes

I require some advise really, I have 2 different themes and what I want to do is depending on what user account they use to login with they will access a different theme.I've been told implementing a membership provider would help me do this?.

Comment: Do you already have user accounts?

Comment: yes using .net membership framework you can put your themes in different folders and assign roles so as to allow/deny to respected users only, go for it

Comment: Not as of yet I just have 2 themes set up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366514%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) as a reference to using themes in ASP.NET. But take note to the section that has the following code `public void Page_PreInit()`, that's the script you're going to need to set the theme dynamically. Your code will look much different because you're going to be leveraging the user that's logged in, but setting it won't change.